# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS boots slow and I get blocking message

Tags: boot, 16.04

Is this expected or is there anything wrong with my machine?

[image: Booting time blocking message]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message is expected and as far as you can tell from it, there's nothing wrong with your machine. That message is not a bad one. 'blocks' are just bits of data that were counted, and the message means the filesystem of `/dev/sda9` is 'clean' or consistent, which is good news.

Comment: On 16.04 this seems to happen every boot.

Comment: Oh yeah! I see it in the ugly verbose boot process of my locally compiled kernel (not the packaged ones), but it doesn't seem to get logged anywhere. Thanks for pointing that out... I edited but still not much use I guess.

Comment: I only noticed because it kicks out of the 'quiet splash' for a second.